# Using the $.ajax to get a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 to build an application, but i'm having a problem when trying to get a partial view; Here's my code

The view :

```
@{while (Model.Read())
{
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li id="general" class="active">Informations générals</li>
        <li id="contact">Contacts</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="contentDetail">
        <div><b>Description :</b> @Model["Description"]</div>
        <div><b>Activity :</b> @Model["Activity"]</div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#contact").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Content("~/Company/Contacts/")',
                type: 'get',
                data: JSON.stringify('@Model["Id"]'),
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#contentDetail').replaceWith(data);
                    },
                error: function (request, status, err) {
                    alert(status);
                    alert(err);
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

}

The controller :

```
public ActionResult Contacts(int id)
    {
        return PartialView("_Contacts", getContactDetails(id));
    }
```

"_Contacts" is my partial view, it's strongly typed.

Home I was clear, thanks ^^

Comment: What is the "problem"?  Have you monitored the HTTP request and response to see what data you're sending and what you're getting back?  Do you know what the HTTP response code is?  Have you checked the error logs on your server to see if that's where your issue is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is wrong:

```
data: JSON.stringify('@Model["Id"]')
```

Replace it with a real JSON object:

```
data: JSON.stringify(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new { id = Model["Id"] }))))
```

or with:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: "@Model["Id"]" })
```

which when rendered in the final markup will look like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ id: "123" })
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ^^
`data: JSON.stringify({ id: '@Model["Id"]' })`

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to return a view not partialview and try this js

```
var model = { id:"@Model["Id"]" };
 $.post("~/Company/Contacts/,
   model,
   function (data) {
      $('#contentDetail').replaceWith(data);
   });
```

here is a blog post on it with sample code  http://bob-the-janitor.blogspot.com/2011/11/more-ajax-with-mvc-using-partial-views.html